# Sqitch - single plan row, multiple sql files

Tags: sqitch

I'm looking to move to sqitch, but my team likes their migrations as multiple files. That is, for example, if we create a foreign key *and* create an index in the same jira ticket, we like `PROJ-123-create-fk.sql` and `PROJ-123-create-index.sql`.

I'd *like* to keep a single row in the `sqitch.plan` file, so that each jira ticket corresponds to a single row.

Basically, short of adding lines to `sqitch.plan`, can I do this? Is there a way to "include" other sql files from a master one? Something like

`PROJ-123-main.sql`

```
\include PROJ-123-create-fk.sql
\include PROJ-123-create-index.sql
```

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\ir` psql directive solved this for me.

in `PROJ-123-deploy.sql`

```
\ir PROJ-123-create-fk.sql
\ir PROJ-123-create-index.sql
```

If the fk and index sql files are in the same directory, they will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to store it as a single line in the plan file, it doesn't quite match, but I will explain the method we use below. Maybe there are parts that you want to use in it.

There is a similar situation in my team, but we use `sqitch tags`. Each version of our application corresponds to a subtask. And each task corresponds to a tag. We create sql files as many as the number of subtasks. Then we combine them in a tag that we created with the name of the main task. In our CI/CD pipeline that we use for the database, we also provide the transition between versions with tags. I wanted to add this method here in case anyone prefers to use a similar structure.

---

Simple example;

Let's have `v2.0` of our application installed and a new table and an index are required for `v2.1`

We create two subtasks named create table and create index under the main task named `v2.1`

We create two sql files;
`app_v2.1_table_create.sql` to create a table, `app_v2.1_index_create.sql` to create an index.

After that, we create a `sqitch tag` called `v2.1`. Notice it has the same name as the main task.